# None Type en consola

Tags: python

Intento hacer un ejercicio que consta de si el usuario ingresa un numero del 1-12 devuelva el nombre del mes correspondiente.
En base a esa funcion, crear otra que represente una fecha determinada. Por ejemplo *fecha_palabra(1,6,1999) == "1 de Junio de 1999"*. Utilizando en la parte del mes, la funcion anterior definida.

```
def meses(mes):

    if (mes == 1):
        print("Enero")
    elif (mes == 2):
        print("Febrero")
    elif (mes == 3):
        print("Marzo")
    elif (mes == 4):
        print("Abril")
    elif (mes == 5):
        print("Mayo")
    elif (mes == 6):
        print("Junio")
    elif (mes == 7):
        print("Julio")
    elif (mes == 8):
        print("Agosto")
    elif (mes == 9):
        print("Septiembre")
    elif (mes == 10):
        print("Octubre")
    elif (mes == 11):
        print("Noviembre")
    else:
        print("Diciembre")

#D 
def fecha_palabra(d,m,a):
    print(d,"de ",meses(m),"de ",a)
```

Esta son ambas funciones. Pero al ingresar los datos como en el ejemplo antes mencionado, la consola retorna:
*Junio*
*1 de None de 1999*

Se que se trata de un error por el tipo de dato "None", pero como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Quizás `print(d,"de ",meses(m),"de ",a)`? No se que estes ingresando nada por ninguna parte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque tu función meses no retorna ningún valor. En vez de `print` debería ser `return`. O aun mejor, usa un array en vez de una cadena de if..else.

```
meses = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre']

def fecha_palabra(d,m,a):
    print(d,"de ",meses[m-1],"de ",a)
```

Queda como ejercicio para el lector validar que m esté en el rango [1, 12]

Comment: Al usar return, nuevamente me da None Type. Si, se puede usar un array, pero ejercicio especifica que no se utilicen listas de ningun modo.

Comment: Solo para estar seguro, reemplazaste los `print` por `return` en la funcion `meses` verdad? No en la funcion `fecha_palabra`? De todos modos usar un arreglo es mucho mas elegante. El código de mi respuesta lo probe y funciona

Comment: @Faxziz Perdon, no lei lo de que no puedes usar listas

Comment: Me ha funcionado. Muchas gracias :D